# Adding PPA does not make new packages available

Tags: 10.10, server, ppa, mono

I added the mono PPA (https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+archive/monoxide) to my Maverick Server and did an apt-get update.

However, when I try to install mono, I still get the older version - not the one from the PPA. apt-cache also shows me only the older version.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PPA only has a mono package for Natty, not Maverick. The only package explicitly for  Maverick is Pinta.

You *could* edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (it might have a separate file of its own in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) so the relevant line goes from something like this:

```
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/unstable/ubuntu maverick main
```

To this:

```
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/unstable/ubuntu natty main
```

This won't always work and might even break things but it's only Mono (I don't think anything critical to booting relies on it) so you could just use `ppa-purge` to drop the PPA and go back to stock packages.

Comment: Thanks - I had selected maverick in that drop down, but forgot to hit the 'filter' button :)